# How to print a specific key from a string of dictionaries.

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I wanted to get a one hot data based on the number of elements in the list when using sklearn transform.

Code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from itertools import chain


x = [['1234', '5678', '910', 'baba'], ['8', '1'], 
     [], ['9', '3'], [], ['7', '6'], [], []]
vector = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r".+",  min_df=1, max_df=1.0, lowercase=False,
                 max_features=None)
vec = [xxx for xx in x for xxx in xx]
vector.fit(chain.from_iterable([vec]))
print(vector.get_feature_names())
new = []
for xx in x:
    new.append(vector.transform(xx))
for x in new:
    for xx in x.toarray():
        print(xx)
```

Current output:

```
['1', '1234', '3', '5678', '6', '7', '8', '9', '910', 'baba']
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

My expected output:

```
['1', '1234', '3', '5678', '6', '7', '8', '9', '910', 'baba']
[0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
```

Is there a way to do it using my code? I have tried to change it many times but unfortunately to no luck. Somehow, my brain stops to process anything now.

Comment: That's not one hot at all. What is it supposed to be and why does it look like that? Can you explain?

Comment: It supposed to be the same like from my "expected output". Why does it look like that. That is the question I would like to know myself too, sir.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need explicit `for` loops for this task. You can use `MultiLabelBinarizer` instead, also from the `sklearn` library. It doesn't handle empty lists, so just filter those out first.

Here's an example with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

L = [['1234', '5678', '910', 'baba'], ['8', '1'], 
     [], ['9', '3'], [], ['7', '6'], [], []]

s = pd.Series(list(filter(None, L)))

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

res = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(s),
                   columns=mlb.classes_,
                   index=s.index)

print(res)

   1  1234  3  5678  6  7  8  9  910  baba
0  0     1  0     1  0  0  0  0    1     1
1  1     0  0     0  0  0  1  0    0     0
2  0     0  1     0  0  0  0  1    0     0
3  0     0  0     0  1  1  0  0    0     0
```

Comment: Hi sir, thank you so much for building the codes for me, but is it possible to alter only according to my codes? I would like to try it with CountVectorizer instead of Multilabelbinarizer

Comment: @JJson, Sorry, I'm not sure how I'd get your logic working with `CountVectorizer`.

Comment: I see. Thank you and I will try to work it out somehow. thanks again

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/29352/sklearn-countvectorizer-token-pattern-skip-token-if-pattern-match

Here is another person who did it using CountVectorizer but unfortunately, even no matter how I changed my regex is still wont work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try of using **intersect** and **np isin**

intersect function will give closed elements and isin will create boolean list

```
mask = ['1', '1234', '3', '5678', '6', '7', '8', '9', '910', 'baba']
for xx in x:
    if len(xx)>1:
        print(np.isin(mask,np.array(list(set(xx).intersection(set(mask))))).astype(int))
```

Out:

```
[0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
```

Flattening the lists

```
#if you have big lists of elements you can flatten by 
sum(x,[])
```

Out:

```
['1234', '5678', '910', 'baba', '8', '1', '9', '3', '7', '6']
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:

I somehow solved it with a SUPER NAIVE way.

Here is the codes:

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from itertools import chain

```
x = [['1234', '5678', '910', 'baba'], ['8', '1'], 
     [], ['9', '3'], [], ['7', '6'], [], []]
vector = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r"\S*\d+\S*",  min_df=1, max_df=1.0, lowercase=False,
                 max_features=None)
vec = [xxx for xx in x for xxx in xx]
vector.fit(chain.from_iterable([vec]))
print(vector.get_feature_names())
new = []
for xx in x:
    new.append(" ".join(xx))

neww = vector.transform(new)

print(neww.toarray())
```